# Translate and scale UIView in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, frame, cgaffinetransform

I want to animate a view by centering one of it's points to the center of the screen and then scale it up.

So, if I have this screen (`S`) with a view (`V`) in it, and a certain point (`x`):

```
+-------------+
|S-----------+|
||V          ||
||           ||
||           ||
||           ||
||           ||
||  x        ||
||           ||
|+-----------+|
+-------------+
```

I want it to animate to this position:

```
   +-----------+
+---V---------+|
|S |          ||
|  |          ||
|  |          ||
|  |          ||
|  |   x      ||
|  |          ||
|  +----------|+
|             |
|             |
+-------------+
```

where the point is centered in the screen, and then scale it like this:

```
+-------------------+
|V                  |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|+-------------+    |
||S            |    |
||             |    |
||             |    |
||             |    |
||      x      |    |
||             |    |
||             |    |
||             |    |
||             |    |
|+-------------+    |
+-------------------+
```

however, I can't accomplish this, even using `CGAffineTransformConcat`, which I though is it designed exactly for cases like this.

I have tried this:

```
CGAffineTransform translateTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(deltaPoint.x, deltaPoint.y);
CGAffineTransform scaleTransform = CGEqualAffineTransformMakeScale(40);

self.screenView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(translateTransform, scaleTransform);
```

where `deltaPoint` is a `CGPoint` having it's `x` and `y` equal to the distance between the point's absolute coordinates (relative to the screen) and the coordinates of the center of the screen, but it animates the point slightly to the right.

I also tried calculating the `deltaPoint` after scaling to no avail:

```
self.screenView.transform = CGEqualAffineTransformMakeScale(40);

// calculate deltaPoint

self.screenView.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.screenView.transform, deltaPoint.x, deltaPoint.y);
```

In both cases, if I comment out the scaling transform, the translation works, it moved it perfectly center, so the problem isn't in the `deltaPoint` calculation.

Comment: Have you tried the concat with the order reversed?

Comment: @Eiko, Yes, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to scale your view with scale factor (Sx, Sy) and move the point (x0, y0) to (x1, y1). And you calculated `dx,dy`. So let do some calculation:

```
Sx.x0 + a = x0 + dx => a = dx - (Sx-1).x0
Sy.y0 + b = y0 + dy => b = dy - (Sy-1).y0
```

With `Sx = Sy = 40` so we have `a = dx - 39.x0` and `b = dx - 39.y0`. So we have transform vector like that

```
CGAffineTransform scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMake(40, 0, 0, 40, a, b);
self.screenView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(translateTransform, scaleTransform);
```

`x0, y0` is your original point `x` in view `v`, before any transformation. You can call it `pointX.x, pointX.y`.
You are using scale factor is `40` in your example so I re-use it. So that `Sx-1` and `Sy - 1` will return the same value, `39`.

Comment: The problem is that after setting the `anchorPoint`, my view moves in a wrong position, so the point `x` is no longer in the center.

Comment: I think this is an error: `CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransform scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMake(40, 0, 0, 40, a, b);`. Also, what is `a` and `b`?

Comment: This is my error when copy - paste. I already give the calculation for `a` and `b`

Comment: with `x0` and `y0` is the position in `v` before transformation.

Comment: And what does `39.x0` mean?

Comment: Ok, I explained again in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83736/discussion-between-iulian-onofrei-and-sahara108).

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is after the view v and point x translates to its required position, you wanted view to be scaled up from the point x, so even after scaling point x remains in the centre of the screen, If it is TRUE then after translation, you need to adjust the anchor point of view such that anchor point of view is equal to x.

Comment: Such that the `anchorPoint` of the view is equal to `x` relative to the `screen`?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose screenView is your view (V)

so you can try something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 // put translation duration here
                 animations:^{
                     self.screenView.center = CGPointMake(self.screenView.center.x + deltaPoint.x, self.screenView.center.y + deltaPoint.y);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:2 // put scale duration here
                                      animations:^{
                                          self.screenView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1); // here the final size will be 110%
                                      }
                                      completion:nil];
                 }
 ];
```

If you want to do this at the same time so simply put the scale in the same block:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 // put translation duration here
                 animations:^{
                     self.screenView.center = CGPointMake(self.screenView.center.x + deltaPoint.x, self.screenView.center.y + deltaPoint.y);
                     self.screenView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1); // here the final size will be 110%
                 }
                 completion:nil
 ];
```

Comment: For your first question, yes. And, I want to translate and scale at the same time.